How do I bake the fluid sim if it does not have a particle system?
I've cached my fluid sim and am ready to export it. I tried selecting the domain and then exporting it as an alembic file but when I import the file into unreal or marmoset toolbag there is no simulation. Any help is appreciated! I am using Blender 4.1. 
